# Enable OCSP stapling on Azure web apps

Tags: azure, cloudflare, ocsp

Need to turn on must-staple for OCSP Stapling on Azure web application.
As far as the discussion on Azure forums are concerned, it seems like for domain like *.azurewebsites.net , OCSP Stapling is enabled by default. But for my Dev URL, which is also in *.azurewebsites.net domain, it does not show the "must-staple" as true/turned on.

The scan for this feature can be run through
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Can anyone help on how to get it enabled for Azure Web Apps and Cloudflare as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft is still working on Enabling stapling for Custom domain, that could be the reason why you are unable to see "Must-Staple" turned on .

Below Document will help you to understand the details about enabling OCSP

[OCSP Enabling](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/21fddbf2-b73d-4193-ba34-18885d412bc4/azure-app-service-ocsp-stapling-enablement?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your input.
I read through this, and since my concern here is not the custom domain, but *.azurewebsites.net. For this, it should be enabled by default, which is not enabled in my case.
Any idea on how to enable it ?

Comment: Any updates on OCSP stapling for Azure App Service (especially set up as code running ASP.Net 4.8 but used only for with static content and some  Server Side Include of static content) without having to separately enable Azure Application Gateway in front of Azure App Service ?